# Spacing between image and text in pgfplot legend

Tags: pgfplots

Using the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0, xmax=4, ymin=0, ymax=10,
width=9cm, height=6cm,
legend style={draw=none}]

\addplot[only marks,color=red] coordinates {
(0, 10) (0.5, 8.5) (1, 2) (2, 0.5) (3.5, 1.9)};
\addlegendentry{Experimental Data Point}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I am getting the image:

[image]

The symbol in the legend is a bit close to the legend text for my taste. Is there anyway to increase the spacing between the two?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the `pgfplots` manual,

> The legend is a TikZ-matrix, so one can use any TikZ option which affects nodes and matrices [...]. The matrix is created by something like
>
> ```
> \matrix[style=every axis legend] {
>     draw plot specification 1 & \node{legend 1}\\
>     draw plot specification 2 & \node{legend 2}\\
>     ...
> };
> ```

Thus, you can increase the `column sep` of the `legend style` to achieve the desired effect.

## Code

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=0, xmax=4, ymin=0, ymax=10,
width=9cm, height=6cm,
legend style={draw=none,column sep=10pt}]

\addplot[only marks,color=red] coordinates {
(0, 10) (0.5, 8.5) (1, 2) (2, 0.5) (3.5, 1.9)};
\addlegendentry{Experimental Data Point}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Interesting, I saw 'column sep' in the manual but I didn't realize  it could separate the image from the text . For some mistaken reason I thought it only separated legend entries.

Answer (score 3):

How about using `\hphantom{A}` in the legend entry to increase the space between the two.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=4, ymin=0, ymax=10,
width=9cm, height=6cm, legend pos= north east,
legend style={}]
\addplot[only marks,color=red] coordinates {
(0, 10) (0.5, 8.5) (1, 2) (2, 0.5) (3.5, 1.9)};
\addlegendentry{\hphantom{A}Experimental Data Point}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's simple and it works.